# Can't get my jsp to store the integer value from my result set

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp

All I am trying to do is pull the integer value from the cell. When I run the command in my sql workbench I get the proper value [screenshot of db output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHDOm.png) however when I execute the code in programming environment I get "An exception occurred processing [/registration.jsp] at line [24]" which is this line `idnum = rs.getInt("MAX(idnum)")+1;` The program has an initial html page where the use enters the desired password, first name and last name. it then sends the info to the jsp which is supposed to take that information increment the user id by 1 from whatever the highest value is currently then create a new table entry with said information.

```
int idnum = 0;
String pwd = request.getParameter("pwd");
String fname = request.getParameter("fname");
String lname = request.getParameter("lname");
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/assignment2", "root",
        "has the actual password in the code");
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
String query = "SELECT MAX(idnum) FROM users";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

idnum = rs.getInt("MAX(idnum)")+1;
```

Comment: what happens if you try `rs.getInt(1)` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
idnum = rs.getInt("MAX(idnum)")+1;
```

with

```
if (rs.next())
    idnum = rs.getInt(1)+1;
```

Note that without calling the `next()` method, the result set pointer/cursor will not move to the 1st row (from default position).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
String query = "SELECT MAX(idnum) as maxNum FROM users";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

if(rs.next(){
     idnum = rs.getInt("maxNum")+1;
}
```